# discontinuity of function

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

The function $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0   ,  & \text{ y$\lt$o} \\
\sin x+2\cos y, & \text{ 0 $\le{y}\lt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$}\\
\cos x+2\sin y, &\text{$\frac{\pi}{2} \le{y}\lt\pi$}\\
\cos x     ,&\text{$y\ge\pi$} 
\end{cases}$$

The axes where $f$ is discontinuous are

i) $y=0, y={\frac{\pi}{2}}$ & $y={\pi}$

ii) $y=0, y={\frac{\pi}{2}}$

iii) $y={\frac{\pi}{2}}$ & $y={\pi}$

iv) nowhere

Fix $x$

$\lim_{y\to 0^{-}}f(x,y)=0$ and $\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\sin x+2\cos y=\sin x+2$

Left and right hand side limits are not same . Hence not continuous at $y=0$.

$\lim_{y\to {\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-}}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to {\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-}}\sin x+2\cos y=\sin x$ and $\lim_{y\to {\frac{\pi}{2}}^{+}}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\cos x+2\sin y=\cos x+2$

Hence not continuous at $\frac{\pi}{2}$

similarly I can show that function is continuous at $\pi$

Hence option (ii) is correct.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, option $(ii)$ is the right answer. To prove discontinuity at a point, we just have to show that two path that leads to different value at that point.